# How to create a nuget package from DLLs after obfuscating them

Tags: c#, dll, nuget-package, obfuscation, nuget-spec

Hi I have a `class Library` project I built it `DLLs` and **I apply obfuscation on the DLLs** using a software, after that I got new obfuscated `DLLs`.

so now my question is **how can I create `nuget` package just from the obfuscated `DLLs` ?**

thank you in advance.

Comment: Modern obfuscators usually provide a task for MSBuild (e.g https://www.armdot.com/docs/msbuild-obfuscation-task.html) that allows to obfuscate the assembly. So the package already includes obfuscated assemblies.

Comment: Hi, have u found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, One is using `post-build event` to automatically create nukpkg.

Some code:

```
//Add your obfucate code     

//--no-build is needed
dotnet pack --no-build

//upload to nuget
nuget setapikey xxx -source xxxxxx
nuget push xx.nupkg -source xxxxxx
```

Or you can use [NuGetPackageExplorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) to manually create a nupkg and upload to nuget manually.